# Why textBody.Append is only appending the table header to the first record not others?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net, dataset

I am looping over the dataset and pikcing fields and putting into the html table which I am sending using the email. It works but only the first row is coming proper but not the next rows. why?

```
Dim textBody As New StringBuilder
textBody.Append("<p> <b> Dear " & dsEmails.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("FullName") & ",</b> <br /> <br /> Kindly review the timesheets of employees who have partially filled the records for week" + PreviousWeek.ToString() + "</b> <br /><br /> <br /></p>").AppendLine()
textBody.Append("<br><table rules='all' bordercolor='#4d4c4d' border='1' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' cellpadding='8'  align='center' width='500'>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>TotalHours</th>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>").AppendLine()

For Each row As DataRow In CTRData.Tables(0).Rows

    textBody.Append("<td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;' > " + row("Employee_Name").ToString() + "</td>").AppendLine()
    textBody.Append("<td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;'>" + row("OverallHrs").ToString() + " </td>").AppendLine()
    textBody.Append("<td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;' > " + row("Week").ToString() + " </td>").AppendLine()
    textBody.Append("<td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;'>" + row("Year").ToString() + " </td>").AppendLine()
    textBody.Append("</tr></table>").AppendLine()

    Next
```

Comment: Start by putting the second `<tr>` inside the ForEach loop... It now generates invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

To generate your html markup correctly your code need to become:

```
    Dim textBody As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    textBody.AppendLine("<p>")
    textBody.AppendLine("    <b> Dear " & CStr(dsEmails.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("FullName")) & ",</b> ")
    textBody.AppendLine("    <br /> <br /> Kindly review the timesheets of employees who have partially filled the records for week" & PreviousWeek.ToString() & " </b>")
    textBody.AppendLine("    <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />")
    textBody.AppendLine("</p>")


    ' Table init
    textBody.AppendLine("<table rules='all' bordercolor='#4d4c4d' border='1' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' cellpadding='8'  align='center' width='500'> ")

    textBody.AppendLine("<tr>")
    textBody.AppendLine("   <th>Employee</th>")
    textBody.AppendLine("   <th>TotalHours</th>")
    textBody.AppendLine("   <th>Week</th>")
    textBody.AppendLine("   <th>Year</th>")
    textBody.AppendLine("</tr>")


    For Each row As DataRow In CTRData.Tables(0).Rows
        textBody.AppendLine("<tr>")
        textBody.AppendLine("    <td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;'>" & row("Employee_Name").ToString() & "</td>")
        textBody.AppendLine("    <td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;'>" & row("OverallHrs").ToString() & " </td>")
        textBody.AppendLine("    <td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;'>" & row("Week").ToString() & " </td>")
        textBody.AppendLine("    <td bgcolor='#da5903' style='height:  5px;'>" & row("Year").ToString() & " </td>")
        textBody.AppendLine("</tr>")
    Next


    textBody.Append("</table>").AppendLine()
    'Table closure
```

Also change all attributes in your table and td tags, use valid html5 attributes instead, like style=’border:solid 1px #333’ etc….